# analyzing inputstream xml format java

Tags: java, xml, inputstream

I have an [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) containing xml format like the following :-

```
InputStream is = asStream("<TransactionList>\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"C\" amount=\"1000\"narration=\"salary\" />\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"X\" amount=\"400\" narration=\"rent\"/>\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"D\" amount=\"750\" narration=\"other\"/>\n" +
            "</TransactionList>");
 xmlTransactionProcessor.importTransactions(is);
```

I'm trying to analyze this and store the values into an array-list of Transaction object (user-defined), but I am still unable to do so.

I tried many solutions but I am still not getting any benefits.

I read about reading xml files but still am not able to deal with an InputStream like this.

Can anybody help ? This is my last try but it is still failing somewhere .

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String inline = "";
    try {
        while ((inline = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(inline);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

    try {
        org.jdom2.Document document = (org.jdom2.Document) builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Another good option is [tag:jaxb].

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to parse the XML yourself with SAX parser.  There are several libraries that allow [XML Binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding): serialize and deserialize XML documents into custom POJO classes (or collection of these).

There is even a standard for XML binding in the JDK.  It is called [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/).  You can use annotations to map the XML element names to the properties of your custom POJO.

Here's an example with my personal favorute library: [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). It is primarily desgined to process JSON formatted text, but has [an extension](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) to support XML (and JAXB).

```
import java.util.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.*;

public class XMLTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = 
            "<TransactionList>\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"C\" amount=\"1000\" narration=\"salary\" />\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"X\" amount=\"400\" narration=\"rent\"/>\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"D\" amount=\"750\" narration=\"other\"/>\n" +
            "</TransactionList>";
        try {
            XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            xmlMapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
            // this is how we tell Jackson the target type of the deserialization 
            JavaType transactionListType = xmlMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Transaction.class);
            List<Transaction> transactionList = xmlMapper.readValue(input, transactionListType );
            System.out.println(transactionList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Transaction
    {
        public String type;
        public int amount;
        public String narration;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{ type:%s, amount:%d, narration:%s }", type, amount, narration);   
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ill try this solution later , now its working fine with the another solution , but its a good idea to try many solutions

Comment: what do you mean "the another solution", the manual sax parsing?? this is by far a better, safer, faster to develop, and much more readable solution.

Comment: the solution in the another answer , just worked with it then noticed this solutions , yes its seems faster , ill try it

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Sharon Ben Asher, you could use annotated data mapping using [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) or [Jackson with XML data formatter](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization). This would be easier.

If you want to fix your existing code using the SAXParser here's how it is.

You have to iterate the document object as in the code below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(("<TransactionList>\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"C\" amount=\"1000\" narration=\"salary\" />\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"X\" amount=\"400\" narration=\"rent\"/>\n" +
            "    <Transaction type=\"D\" amount=\"750\" narration=\"other\"/>\n" +
            "</TransactionList>").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ArrayList transactions = importTransactions(is);
}
```

In the `importTransaction` method use `getRootElement` to get the root level **Transactions** element. Then iterate through each of the **Transaction** child elements using `getChildren` and a for-each loop.

```
public static ArrayList<Transaction> importTransactions(InputStream is){
        ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String inline = "";
        try {
            while ((inline = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(inline);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

        try {
            org.jdom2.Document document = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes()));
            Element transactionsElement = document.getRootElement();

            List<Element> transactionList = transactionsElement.getChildren();

            for (Element transaction:transactionList) {
                Transaction t = new Transaction();
                t.setType(transaction.getAttribute("type").getValue());
                t.setAmount(transaction.getAttribute("amount").getValue());
                transactions.add(t);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the error....
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return transactions;
    }
```

Comment: thanks very much for responding , it works perfect , you saved my day .. i really appreciate this

Comment: for this solution , the value of "transaction.getAttribute("amount") " is 
 " [Attribute: amount="1000"] ", how to extract only the value of amount (1000)?

Comment: got it  , by just using getValue like transaction.getAttribute("amount").getValue();